# Hide Container but not Text Positioned Over It

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a .NET 4.5 WinForm that checks for the existence of a certain file when the form loads. If the condition is met, I display the form in its entirety. If the file doesn't exist, I want to display a simple text message while hiding (setting the `Visible` property to false) all the other components on the form.
My issue is that the `Label` I want to display can only be positioned on top of a `GroupBox`. Well, not *only* but it is most aesthetically pleasing being in that location. If I set the visibility of the container to false then it hides the message as well.

[image: misbehaving label]

Is there a way to "break out" the Label from the GroupBox?
Worst comes to worst, I will hide the indivial components within the GroupBox and live with the border that remains. I am just curious if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using only the designer. ChrisF's answer got me thinking, and the correct method isn't to place the label behind the container, but rather to place the container on top of the label. This seems to be a quirk of the VS designer.
I created a new WinForm and added a label and a groupbox, without the two of them overlapping. Then:

1. Right-click the label and *Send to Back*, or alternatively right-click the container and *Send to Front*
2. Drag or resize the container to cover the label

And that's it... the label appears behind the container. I guess the designer correctly notes the z-index when both components have the same parent container, and placing the label on top of the groupbox changes its parent container.

Comment: Use `View - Other Windows - Document Outline` to control the parent placement of the controls.

Answer (score 0):

To have the label on the form in the position you want, but outside the group box use the "send to back" option to push it behind the group box. It won't be visible at design time, but it will be in the right place.

Then if the file is not found you can make the group box invisible revealing the label behind.

Another alternative is to position the label outside the group box (off to the left or right and outside the form) and then move it into position at the same time as making it visible.

Comment: Suprisingly this didn't work! "Send to back" moved the Label behind the `DataGridView` you see in the screenshot, but it still remained a child of the `GroupBox` container. Has this method worked for you before?

Comment: @valsidalv - I'm sure it has, but it's been a while and I didn't have chance to double check it over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to benefit the capability of design support to position your label correctly right at design time, however doing so will set the groupbox as Parent of your label, you **can't** drag and drop that label on your form. So just try the following code to change the Parent from groupbox to the form at runtime and maintain the *design location*, that way changing your groupbox's visible won't affect the visible of your label:

```
public Form1(){
  InitializeComponent();
  Load += (s,e) => {
    var loc = label1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
    label1.Parent = this;
    label1.Location = PointToClient(loc);
  };
}
```

Comment: This almost works. The label is now visible but it shows up at the top of my window (a little above the "Select Filter Profile" dropbox in my image). It still maintains the correct X-coordinate however.

Comment: @valsidalv see updated code. I would expect that there might be **a little** offset (not much as you said), there may be a reason that the location of label1 has not been updated at that point, we can run the code in the `Load` event handler, now it should work, otherwise I couldn't imagine what's wrong here.

Comment: The updated code doesn't change anything from the previous code - it still gets pushed up in position. I figured out a solution using only the designer, will update. Thanks for the help.